# Writing only some pixels during ANativeWindow_lock()

Tags: android, android-ndk

I noticed some strange behaviour when writing only some pixels to the pixel buffer obtained using ANativeWindow_lock(). Let's assume I want to draw a line from (0|0) to (320|240). To do that, I'm calling ANativeWindow_lock() with the boundaries parameter set to something like:

```
ARect b;
b.left = 0;
b.top = 0;
b.right = 320;
b.bottom = 240;
```

Then I draw my line using Bresenham's algorithm to the pixel buffer. Because the line is not straight, I only have to modify very few pixels in the pixel buffer obtained from ANativeWindow_lock(). It's mostly just one pixel per scanline in the pixel buffer that is modified by my Bresenham implementation. The rest of the pixel buffer remains untouched.

Now comes the strange behaviour: When I now call ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost() all pixels that I did NOT modify often contain some random colors and NOT the color that was last drawn to it. This is confusing me: Why do these pixels do not keep the color values that I last wrote to them?

Consider the following case to understand what is going on:

1. Fill entire screen with blue.
2. Fill entire screen with red.
3. Draw a diagonal line across entire screen.
4. Now the parts of the pixel buffer that I did not modify suddenly appear in BLUE although I have cleared the screen to be completely RED just before drawing the line.

Does anybody have an explanation why this is happening? The only way around this is to always modify ALL pixels in the pixel buffer obtained from ANativeWindow_lock(). But of course this often means a lot of overhead if only some pixels have to be drawn, for example in the case of a line!

Tested on Android 2.3 and 3.1.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Turner explained what is going on the Android NDK mailing list: Android uses double or even triple buffering and that's why one cannot make any assumptions on what is in the pixel buffer when calling ANativeWindow_lock() and always has to refresh all pixels in the rectangle that shall be updated.